# What is the procedure for UAE Embassy Attestation?

Tags: uae

I am looking for job opportunities in the UAE,I am from India. I heard that if I want to go to the UAE, I have to complete the UAE Embassy Attestation procedure in India. So can anyone guide me through the procedure?

Comment: What research have you done up to now? Have you looked at the web site of the UAE Embassy in your country of residence/citizenship?

Comment: You can get your documents attested online from [Benchmark attestation](http://www.onlineattestation.com). Their services are pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

**UAE Embassy Attestation Procedure:**

Embassy Attestation procedure for UAE begins at the verification by local officials in India. The authentication of certificates is required which can be accessed by accomplishing legalization from all other important departments as well. The process is completed by Notary, Home Department or HRD, SDM at times, MEA and the particular embassy.

**Regional Level Authentication:** It is the starting level of the certificate authentication process. This stage of authentication can be done by the notary or the University at the regional level from where the documents were issued, as per the prerequisite.

**State Government Authentication:** The authentication of certificates from the state is performed by three different departments according to the need of the document type. These departments are the Human Resource Department, the State Home Department, and the Sub-Divisional Magistrate or SDM. Sub-Divisional Magistrate is independent of the state government, although, the verification done by this specialist is considered on the state level.

**MEA Stamp:** Ministry of External Affairs is the central government department that deals with foreign affairs in India. MEA or Ministry of External Affairs is the last phase of verification from the Government after which an MEA stamp is attached to the document.

**Embassy Attestation:** UAE Embassy Attestation is done by the officials of the UAE Embassy to legalize documents. It is the final stage of the certificate legalization for UAE after the Ministry of External Affairs.

**MOFA Attestation:** Ministry Of Foreign Affairs (MOFA) attestation is performed by the government of the United Arab Emirates. The consulate provides a signature & stamp on the documents to make it valid to be submitted to the government.

It is important to make sure that the legal documents are processed with the proper course of action & handled carefully. UAE Attestation is an indirect procedure and should be done after understanding all the details about it properly. This generally requires professional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do all [certificate attestation](https://businessgatetranslation.com/service/certificate-attestation-services/) procedures.  You need to attest all your certificates from India MOFA and Embassy of UAE in India so that you can get UAE MOFA attestation as the authorities do not accept any certficate without the attestation of UAE MOFA.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon on your job, such as working for hospitals, schools, government sectors, engineering, the first step in the process would be getting HRD attestation from the concerned state in India.

For all other job profiles, your degree must be attested by Notary, Home department Mantralaya/Sub divisional magistrate (SDM), Ministry of External Affairs Delhi (MEA), Patiala House and UAE Embassy in India.

Further more, once you reach UAE, the document needs to be attested by the UAE Ministry of Foreign Affairs and that concludes the embassy attestation procedure.

From my personal experience, these are time taking processes (almost 8 working days), hence I took support from local [attestation services](https://www.attest.ae) company in Dubai.

Hope this helps.